AWS Quicksight - How to Dynamically update the data based on the filters
New to quicksight. I have a filter in my table called Start Date and a calculated field called Total Hours.
How can I update either of these fields/filters for the Total Hours in my table to be updated based  on the start date filter?
I cannot find a suitable option that updates the fields based on the filter.
